# Am I able to use CSS grid or flexbox with setAttribute('class','className') method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, setattribute

I would just like to know if I Am able to use CSS grid or flexbox settings with the setAttribute('class','className') method in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm sorry I mean to say set Attribute I am new to learning JS please forgive me @Peter B.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding It has now been updated.

Comment: Yes it's possible, as long as the class has a proper CSS definition then it should work.